# How to dectect new or modified files in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, file, filesystems, fsevents

In Windows OS, MS provides ReadDirectoryChangesW and FindFirstChangeNotification API to dectect new or modified file, does the Mac OSX provide equal function as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mac OS X Leopard [monitor file changes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/cocoa/filesystemevents.html) with the [File System Events API](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I found the API can work only with 10.5 or above, how to support 10.3 and 10.4? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why I wrote Mac OS X "Leopard" (10.5) as older Mac OS versions may require ugly hacks if they don't have this new feature.  From May 2005, under 10.4:  http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 3):

See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents/0.2.1 for a Python implementation.

Answer (score 2):

OS X provides a framework called [FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), I don't know much about the specifics of it though.

Comment: Nor do I. But ___[this page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060817044149264)___, and links off it may be helpful.