# How do I create an MD5 Hash of a string in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hash, md5

I know SHA-1 is preferred, but this project requires I use MD5.

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>

- (NSString*) MD5Hasher: (NSString*) query {
    NSData* hashed = [query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char *digest = MD5([hashed bytes], [hashed length], NULL);
    NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)digest];
    return final;
}
```

I got this code from an answer to another similar question on StackOverflow, but I get the following error from GDB when the program breaks at *return final;*

```
(gdb) p digest
$1 = (unsigned char *) 0xa06310e4 "\0206b\260/\336\316^\021\b\a/9\310\225\204"
(gdb) po final
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) po digest

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0xb0623630
0x98531ed7 in objc_msgSend ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(_NSPrintForDebugger) will be abandoned.
```

I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is the category I use:

**NSString+MD5.h**

```
@interface NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5String;

@end
```

**NSString+MD5.m**

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5String {
    const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG)strlen(cStr), result );

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
    ];  
}

@end
```

**Usage**

```
NSString *myString = @"test";
NSString *md5 = [myString MD5String]; // returns NSString of the MD5 of test
```

Comment: I importe the NSString+MD5. But Xcode and the compiler says : "no visible interface found for NSString"

Comment: Maybe use the constant CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH and cast to CC_LONG for 64-bit compatibility
 
`const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 
CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG)strlen(cStr), result );`

Comment: - (NSString *)MD5String {
    const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, (int)strlen(cStr), result ); // This is the md5 call
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];

Answer (score 10):

cdespinosa and irsk have already shown you your actual problem, so let me go through your GDB transcript:

> ```
> (gdb) p digest
> $1 = (unsigned char *) 0xa06310e4 "\0206b\260/\336\316^\021\b\a/9\310\225\204"
> ```

You've printed `digest` as a C string. You can see here that this string is raw bytes; hence all the octal escapes (e.g., `\020`, `\225`) and the couple of punctuation characters (`/` and `^`). It is not the printable ASCII hexadecimal representation you were expecting. You're lucky that there were no zero bytes in it; otherwise, you would not have printed the entire hash.

> ```
> (gdb) po final
> Cannot access memory at address 0x0
> ```

`final` is `nil`. This makes sense, as your string above isn't valid UTF-8; again, it's just raw data bytes. `stringWithUTF8String:` requires a UTF-8-encoded text string; you didn't give it one, so it returned `nil`.

For passing raw data around, you'd use NSData. In this case, I think you want the hex representation, so you'll need to create that yourself the way irsk showed you.

Finally, consider how lucky you are that your input didn't hash to a valid UTF-8 string. If it had, you wouldn't have noticed this problem. You may want to construct a unit test for this hash method with this input.

> ```
> (gdb) po digest
>
> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
> Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0xb0623630
> 0x98531ed7 in objc_msgSend ()
> ```

Your program crashed (specific problem: “bad access”, “invalid address”) in `objc_msgSend`. This is because `digest` either is not a Cocoa/CF object at all or was one but was freed. In this case, it's because `digest` is not a Cocoa object; it is a C array of bytes, as shown by your `p digest` line above.

Remember, Objective-C is a superset of C. All of C exists unchanged in it. That means there are C arrays (e.g., `char []`) and Cocoa's NSArrays side by side. Moreover, since NSArray comes from the Cocoa framework, not the Objective-C language, there's no way to make NSArray objects interchangeable with C arrays: You can't use the subscript operator on Cocoa arrays, and you can't send Objective-C messages to C arrays.

Answer (score 10):

Facebook uses this

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```

---

```
+ (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input {
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Or instance method

```
- (NSString *)md5 {
    const char* str = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, (CC_LONG)strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know where the constant CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH comes, it is found by importing CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h in your file

Answer (score 4):

I had used this method:

**NSString+MD5.h**

```
@interface NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5;

@end
```

**NSString+MD5.m**

```
#import "NSString+MD5.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5 {

    const char * pointer = self.UTF8String;
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(pointer, (CC_LONG)strlen(pointer), md5Buffer);

    NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [string appendFormat:@"%02x", md5Buffer[i]];
    }

    return string;
}

@end
```

**Usage:**

```
NSString * myString = @"test";
NSString * md5 = [myString MD5];
```

Comment: +1 for `(CC_LONG)` against `strlen(pointer)` to address the implicit conversion and silence warnings in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that digest is a pointer to a raw binary hash.  In the next line you're attempting to interpret it as a UTF-8 string, but it is most likely not to contain legal UTF-8-encoded character sequences.

I expect what you want is to convert the 16-byte static array of unsigned char into 32 ASCII hexadecimal characters [0-9a-f] using whatever algorithm you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

The MD5 function does not return a C string, it returns a pointer to some bytes. You can't treat it as a string.

If you want to create a string, you need to build a string using the hex values of those bytes. Here is one way to do it as a category on NSData:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
@implementation NSData (MMAdditions)
- (NSString*)md5String
{
    unsigned char md5[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5([self bytes], [self length], md5);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            md5[0], md5[1],
            md5[2], md5[3],
            md5[4], md5[5],
            md5[6], md5[7],
            md5[8], md5[9],
            md5[10], md5[11],
            md5[12], md5[13],
            md5[14], md5[15]
            ];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@implementation NSString (MD5)

+ (NSString *)formattedMD5:(const char *)data length:(unsigned long)len
{
    unsigned char *digest = MD5((unsigned const char *)data, len, NULL);
    NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen((char *)digest); i++)
    {
        char hexValue[4];
        sprintf(hexValue, "%02X", digest[i]);
        [values addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:hexValue length:strlen(hexValue)]];
    }

    // returns a formatted MD5 fingerprint like
    //      00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
    return [values componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (NSString*)MD5:(NSData *) data
    {
        // Create byte array of unsigned chars
        unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

        // Create 16 byte MD5 hash value, store in buffer
        CC_MD5([data bytes], (CC_LONG)data.length, md5Buffer);

        // Convert unsigned char buffer to NSString of hex values
        NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

        return output;
    }
```

How to use

```
NSString *yourStrToBeConverted;
NSData* data = [yourStrToBeConverted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *md5res=[self MD5:data];
```

Comment: how to call this method?

Answer (score -1):

These answers are correct but confusing. I post a working sample, since I had issues with most other answers. The code is tested and works well for Mac OS X 10.12.x and iOS 10.1.x.

YourClass.h

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
@interface YourClass : NSObject
+ (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input;
@end
```

YourClass.m

```
#import YourClass.h

+ (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(cStr, (uint32_t)strlen(cStr), digest);
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]]; //%02X for capital letters
    return output;
}
```

**Usage (e.g. in some other class):**

SomeOtherClass.h

```
#import "YourClass.h"
```

SomeOtherClass.m

```
-(void) Test
{
    //call by [self Test] or use somewhere in your code.
    NSString *password = @"mypassword123";
    NSString *md5 = [YourClass md5:password];
    NSLog(@"%@", password);
    NSLog(@"%@", md5);
}
```