# check downloaded NSData hash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

My app downloads small pictures for different objects, and I save them in phone with a unique fileName. 
I need to check if the image on server has changed. After I download the big pictures, I make a string with date when it was modified. If the date when it was modified has changed, I download new big picture. 
But for small pictures I don't want go on the same way. So I want always download the file, and check a hash of the data to see if it has changed. And if data has a different hash - I will download picture.

Can I check if downloaded data like data saved on device? Are this datas will have same hash?

Comment: The question is a bit contradictory. If you download the image and check hash it to check if its different, you've already downloaded it.Perhaps you want to know if you can get the hash from the server without downloading it? If that is the case, do you have access to the code in the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Stackoverflow question contains a nice NSData category that uses MD5:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2018626/100848

You could instantiate a NSImage and call the above hash method on it's TIFFRepresentation.