# NSString MD5 with hash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Hi have to perform a login via web service sending username and password.
The problem is that the server wants a strange MD5 format of password and I can't generate it.

**Example**

```
NSString password = @".";
NSString md5 = @"5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d";
```

Server MD5 is **"PXñ¯ƒˆc?`œ­·ZuÜ"**.

I need to transform **5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d** in **"PXñ¯ƒˆc?`œ­·ZuÜ"**, but I have no ideas.

**Edit**

I've discovered that the result is an hash of **5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d** string.This is the `.NET` code on server:

```
byte[] passwordBytesEnc = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(".");
byte[] passwordBytesHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytesEnc);
string passwordCriptata = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(passwordBytesHash);
```

Comment: Trying to store an MD5 hash as a UTF8 string is about the most brain damaged thing anyone could do. Add to that that apparently there is no salt involved whatsoever, which is _criminally_ insecure. I'd ask you to tell us which company this is, so we can avoid them.

Comment: And instead of guessing, you could engage your brain, look up which code ñ is, and how it relates to the md5 string. Surely that's a better method than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what your Server expects is the String-representation of the MD5-Hex value (for whatever reason...).

You can convert your Hex-Value to a String like so:

```
NSString *string = @"5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d";
NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //will contain your result-string
int i = 0;
while (i < [string length])
{
    NSString * hexChar = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
    int value = 0;
    sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
    [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
    i+=2;
}
```

(--> [How to convert HEX to NSString in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421282/how-to-convert-hex-to-nsstring-in-objective-c))

Comment: with your code I obtain this string PXñ¯c?`­·ZuÜ and not PXñ¯ƒˆc?`œ­·ZuÜ. I've tried to change NSASCIIStringEncoding in NSUTF8StringEncoding but the result is the same. Ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
- (NSString *)MD5String:(NSString *)string{
    const char *cstr = [string UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"%s",cstr);
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5(cstr, strlen(cstr), result);
    NSLog(@"%s",result);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];
}
```

and call like this

```
NSString *md5 = @"5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d";
    [self MD5String:md5];
```

Comment: Better close the question as duplicate of [How do I create an MD5 Hash of a string in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018550/how-do-i-create-an-md5-hash-of-a-string-in-cocoa) if you believe the answer is a regular MD5. (question was asking for a _strange_ MD5).