# How to generate md5 from String in IOS?

Tags: ios, md5

I am trying to generate MD5 from a String. I successfully generated the key but the problem is that my key is different from android key. I generated the MD5 key using an on-line tool which results the same as android but didn't match to my key. I used the static String to generate MD5 which is

> 1418212369896Sph!nxRock

android MD5 key > d3db2cd07e21b3b55330d6746de32c0d  (this is exact similar to on-line tool)

IOS MD5 key     > 2EC05E18061E51D326BF0BA7889B5413

The code which I used to generate MD5 is below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2018626/1921597

Comment: yes but the problem is that mine key is differ from android and online MD5 key generator tool. and because of this, our server(GET webservice) is responding to android generated key, not for IOS generated key

Comment: Obviously without the key its gonna fail. Either you require to send the key to client device using a service OR use a hardcoded key at both.

Comment: Show us the code that calls the md5 method. The code you have linked works for me. I just created a project and copied that code. It yields `2014-12-10 13:34:03.910 TestObjC[32871:1990043] D3DB2CD07E21B3B55330D6746DE32C0D`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I can't user hardcoded key because its getting generated using some dynamic parameters entered by user and I just want to know that whether I am doing something wrong or if there is wrong my format of key. the online tool I used is 
http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/

Comment: Btw, the md5 string your iOS code creates is the md5 of `14182123`, which is the first part of the string you want to hash.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can I create the MD5 for the whole string I passed which is 1418212369896Sph!nxRock

Comment: Show us your code. If you implemented the linked code **exactly** it's `[@"1418212369896Sph!nxRock" MD5String]`. But that is probably not helpful. Again. Show us the code that calls `MD5String`.

Comment: I have used the exact code given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2018626/1921597

Comment: But how are you calling the code you have linked? As I said earlier the linked method is 100% correct, I check it in a new project. Either you changed it, or the code that calls this method sends the wrong string to the correct method. As I said earlier, the md5 you receive is from the first 8 characters of your string.

Answer (score 24):

I had used this method:

**NSString+MD5.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5;

@end
```

**NSString+MD5.m**

```
#import "NSString+MD5.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5 {

    const char * pointer = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(pointer, (CC_LONG)strlen(pointer), md5Buffer);

    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [string appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

    return string;
}

@end
```

For your string: **1418212369896Sph!nxRock**

Result of your online service is: **d3db2cd07e21b3b55330d6746de32c0d**

Method return: **d3db2cd07e21b3b55330d6746de32c0d**

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is a better answer than the one in the duplicate question. Since this question is likely to be closed, consider adding this answer there.