# AES/CBC/PKCS5 Padding and MD5 in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, aes, md5

I am using the `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` in Android application. Code is like-

```
private static String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

private static String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static String DIGEST = "MD5";

private static Cipher cipher;
private static SecretKey password;
private static IvParameterSpec IVParamSpec;
private final static String pvtkey="GDNBCGDRFSC$%#%=";

//16-byte private key
private static byte[] IV = pvtkey.getBytes();

public PassWordEncryptor() {
    try {

        //Encode digest
        MessageDigest digest;           
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST);            
        password = new SecretKeySpec(digest.digest(pvtkey.getBytes()), ALGORITHM);

        //Initialize objects
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        IVParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.i(Lams4gApp.TAG, "No such algorithm " + ALGORITHM);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println( "No such padding PKCS7"+ e);
    }
}
/**
Encryptor.

@text String to be encrypted
@return Base64 encrypted text

*/
public String encrypt(byte[] text) {

    byte[] encryptedData;

    try {

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, password, IVParamSpec);
        encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println( "Invalid key  (invalid encoding, wrong length, uninitialized, etc)."+ e);
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.println( "Invalid or inappropriate algorithm parameters for " + ALGORITHM+ e);
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        System.out.println( "The length of data provided to a block cipher is incorrect"+ e);
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println( "The input data but the data is not padded properly."+ e);
        return null;
    }               
    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData,Base64.DEFAULT);

}
```

And iOS Code like-

```
- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    //keyPtr = [58,-43,46,33,-105,83,-80,-5,99,59,2,109,63,89,-59,-91];
    key = [key MD5];
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Results are same if I do not use `MD5 digest` in both code. But if I use `MD5` in android and iOS then result differs.This is the issue only in `128 bit` if i use `256` then results are exactly same.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this.

1. In your iOS code, it appears you are calling the `MD5` method on
   `key`, which is just an `NSString`. You need to implement the `MD5`
   digest for that class. [Example
   implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018550/how-do-i-create-an-md5-hash-of-a-string-in-cocoa)
2. In your Java code, you are using the same value for both the key and
   the IV. This is **very dangerous** and can result in leaking the key
   value. Use a unique, random, non-predictable value for the IV for
   every message encrypted with a given key.
3. MD5 is a very weak (in fact, deprecated and not considered "cryptographically-secure") digest function. In this case you are using it as a key derivation function (KDF) to *derive* a *key* from some "human-readable and -memorable" input (usually a password). MD5 derivation will easily be brute forced in a matter of seconds on commodity hardware. Use `bcrypt`, `scrypt`, or `PBKDF2 with HMAC/SHA-256` and a high work factor to derive these keys.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I will check the same. Thank you so much.