# Troubles with converting java code to objective C

Tags: java, objective-c

```
MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String resultPassword = dc.profile.sipUsername + ":" + dc.profile.stunServer + ":" + passwd;
        md.update(resultPassword.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j = 0; j < byteData.length; j++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[j] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
```

I have reached to that point

```
NSData *data = [resultPassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
    NSData *hashData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:digest length: sizeof digest];
```

But don't know am i going on right way. 
I need to convert password to md5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also suggest Jon Skeet's [*Writing the Perfect Question*](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What specific problem are you having? Just "convert this for me" isn't a question by SO's standards.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

NSString *calcMD5(NSString *aString, NSString *key)
{
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [aString cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Berechnung der MD5-Signatur
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgMD5, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                          length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    // Base64 encoded zurückliefern
    return [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

Or use the following if there is no key:
[How do I create an MD5 Hash of a string in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018550/how-do-i-create-an-md5-hash-of-a-string-in-cocoa)